# Save RichTextBox Content to Database

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, richtextbox

I am trying to save all content of a RichTextBox including images to a VARBINARY(MAX) column in a SQL Server 2008 database. Getting text from the RTB is pretty intuitive, but I have not been able to find where I can get text and images.

Is there a property or way that I can get the content for storage in a db? How would I restore the RTB next time it was loaded (if it is just a property that I am accessing, then obviously I would just link the data.

Finally, is there a way to tell if a RTB contains any images? I am adding images to existing code where text is already being saved, and I don't want to duplicate stored data if it is not necessary.

Comment: Did you try getting and setting .Rtf instead of .Text?

Comment: @KeithMifsud That looks like it. Thank you. I looked at that one once before, but it didn't have the data. I think my break point was before the image was copied in. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :) Just for the sake of the question, I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the .Rtf property of the richTextBox

```
RichTextBox1.Rtf
```